# serverless deploy - aws lambda; confluent-kafka error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, confluent-platform, serverless

am trying to import confluent_kafka in aws lambda and getting below mentioned error, (confluent-kafka==0.11.4rc1, librdkafka 0.11.3)

```
Command "/var/lang/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ntio3ka8/confluent-
kafka/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" --no-user-cfg 
install --record /tmp/pip-crmp967f-record/install-record.txt --
single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/tmp/tmp_57pgtu7" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ntio3ka8/confluent-kafka/
```

Am able to import in a local environment and virtual python environment. But when i invoke a function in aws lambda that time got above-mentioned error.

Serverless.yml

```
service: test-one-confluent-kafka
provider:
   name: aws
   runtime: python3.6


functions:
   hello:
     handler: handler.hello

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
     dockerizePip: non-linux
```

handler.py

```
import json
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def hello(event, context):
   print("Test Confluent Kafka")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   hello("","")
```

Comment: Is librdkafka installed separately? If not that might be the problem.

Comment: The upcoming v0.11.4 of confluent-kafka-python will be self-contained and include the C library dependencies, you can try out a release candidate by following the instructions here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/184#issuecomment-370916933

Comment: Thank you for your response. librdkafka install separately using brew install librdkafka, when i tried to run using the above mentioned command, getting error:                                            Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement confluent-kafka==0.11.4rc1 (from -r .serverless/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.9.1.1, 0.9.1.2, 0.9.2, 0.9.4, 0.11.0)
No matching distribution found for confluent-kafka==0.11.4rc1 (from -r .serverless/requirements.txt (line 1))

Comment: Make sure to use test.pypi.org (as in the instructions) since the release candidate is not uploaded to the real PyPi.

Comment: i used that still not working. we dropped the idea and used http.client