# How to install librdKafka package on AWS lambda using serverless tool

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-platform, serverless

I am trying to publish message into Kafka using confluent-kafka(0.11.0) python package. It required librdKafka package. I am using serverless tool writing function and for installing package. For installing package I am following this [doc](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/)

I am not able find the way to install librdKafka package. Is any way to install ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176476/serverless-deploy-aws-lambda-confluent-kafka-error?noredirect=1#comment85369251_49176476

Comment: @Sky, did you get the way?

Comment: @FarheenNilofer No, We was planning to publish messages into Kafka by Lambda but It is very difficult to achieve. We changed the architecture. Lamda will call our microservice and service will publish messages into Kafka.

Comment: @sky - Could you please share the issues that you faced? We are also trying similar architecture. We have created an API endpoint on Lambda and planning to publish messages in Kakfa by writing KafkaProducer in Lambda (EC2 instance)

Comment: @Neil It is one year old issue. The issue was Lambda has some limitations for eg: size it only allows 500MB. We were unable to install Kafka producer library. Not sure it is still there or fixed.

Comment: @sky Thanks for replying back. We were able to install pykafka on lambda as add on. We will see if we can work around 500 MB limit issue

Answer (score 1):

I understand the original question was posted 4 years ago but recently I struggled to create a Lambda Kafka producer with Python that interacted with a Confluent consumer that relied on Avro and Confluent's binary serialization.  Here is how we overcame the challenges without using the confluent Python library thus avoiding the librdKafka dependency.

The confluent deserializer expects the first 5 bytes to be a 0 + 4 digit schema id. You can fetch the schema and its details from the schema registry api:

```
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL + '/subjects/' + topic + '/versions/latest'
```

**Here is how I constructed the 5 byte array:**

These are the first 5 bytes the confluent deserializer expects: 0 then 4 digit schema id

```
confluentBytes = struct.pack('>bi',0,schemaIdFromAPI)
```

You also need to binary serialize your message according to the avro schema. Again use the api url to fetch the schema string.

parse the schema and use the apache avro.io library to serialize:

```
value_schema = avro.schema.parse(schemaString)
```

create the serialization writer

```
writer =avro.io.DatumWriter(value_schema)
bytes_writer=io.BytesIO()
encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
```

write the message you wish to send out as a json object using the DatumWriter and encoder:

```
writer.write(json.loads(msg), encoder)
```

we send a byte array to kafka

```
raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()
```

concatenate the 2 byte arrays and send it along. This is a basic kafka producer using ssl from the python library kafka-python

```
producer.send("YOUR-MSG-TOPIC", confluentBytes + raw_bytes)
```